# MySQL Using %m returns different month than %M

Tags: mysql, datetime

CentOS 6.7
MySQL 5.1.73

I have an archive table that has a column called `dateTime` which is just the unix epoch for each record.

I'm trying to extract the Month name and the month number using the queries below. However, `%M` is correct, but `%m` is not.

The correct result should be `March` and `03`. However `%m` is returning 12.

```
mysql> SELECT max( dateTime ) FROM archive;
+-----------------+
| max( dateTime ) |
+-----------------+
|      1457104500 |
+-----------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> SELECT max( FROM_UNIXTIME(dateTime,"%M") ) as 'date' FROM archive;
+-------+
| date  |
+-------+
| March |
+-------+
1 row in set (0.02 sec)

mysql> SELECT max( FROM_UNIXTIME(dateTime,"%m") ) as 'date' FROM archive;
+------+
| date |
+------+
| 12   |
+------+
1 row in set (0.02 sec)
```

Why is `%m` returning 12?

**Edit**: Here's a fun one. Using `%m %M` yields a different result than `%M %m`

```
mysql> SELECT max( dateTime ) FROM archive;
+-----------------+
| max( dateTime ) |
+-----------------+
|      1457104500 |
+-----------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> SELECT max( FROM_UNIXTIME(dateTime,"%M %m") ) as 'date' FROM archive;
+----------+
| date     |
+----------+
| March 03 |
+----------+
1 row in set (0.02 sec)

mysql> SELECT max( FROM_UNIXTIME(dateTime,"%m %M") ) as 'date' FROM archive;
+-------------+
| date        |
+-------------+
| 12 December |
+-------------+
1 row in set (0.02 sec)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You select the `max` value of the results whih are already converted by `FROM_UNIXTIME`:

12 is the largest numeric result and March is the "largest" alphanumeric result when you sort month names.

I assume you want the largest result and convert it afterwards:

```
FROM_UNIXTIME(MAX(dateTime),"%M")
```

and

```
FROM_UNIXTIME(MAX(dateTime),"%m")
```

is what you want

Comment: It's always the simplest solution that's overlooked. Thanks!